Face error while install target sbf-solana-solana
I was trying to add target sbf-solana-solana by the command\
rustup target add sbf-solana-solana

but i am facing as issue
error: toolchain 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' does not support target 'sbf-solana-solana'
note: you can see a list of supported targets with `rustc --print=target-list`
note: if you are adding support for a new target to rustc itself, see https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/building/new-target.html

if anyone has solution to this issue\
please let me know
Thank You

Solana isn't part of the official Rust toolchain, https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/archive-stable-version-installers.html
This is the script to use to install the solana cli suite
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.anza.xyz/stable/install)"

Solana installation guide -> https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/setup-local-development
